# Rails best way to concatenate a string with a variable in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Essentially I'm trying to perform this comparison

```
request.fullpath == "/contacts/"+current_user.id
```

What is the best way to concatenate a string with a variable to perform a comparison like this?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can interpolate it as  `request.fullpath == "/contacts/#{current_user.id}"`

Answer (score 24):

```
"/contacts/#{current_user.id}"
```

Always use String interpolation, it's faster than `<<` and `+`

Comment: why the string interpolation is faster than others

Comment: @wasipeer string concatenation in this example will create two strings then do the concatenation. Interpolation will create just one. I have found this benchamark somwhere, you can try it yourself. https://gist.github.com/alno/1704455